Remote battery disconnect drains the battery
Installed a remote battery disconnect switch yesterday. I tested once and it worked as intended. Today, after about 24 hours, the car won't start. I checked the battery with a voltmeter and it has only 1.5V left. Can you guys check my wiring see what I did wrong? I can't figure it out. Thanks.


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I don't see anything wrong with the wiring, however, with only 1.5v on the battery when you tested it, I'd suggest you have problem with your battery. It looks as though in the setup of the device, it has constant power on in order to cut the main power to the vehicle. If it is "on" all of the time, it doesn't take long to drain a bad battery.
